# SQL PNG IN A TABLE

Tags: sql, database, png

How can you put PNG files in an sql table?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to store files in a database table, the best way is to store them in a server and save the file URL into a varchar field.

Example: Save your file example.png in the public folder, then insert into your table a string with the full URL path of your URL such as "https://yourserver.com/public/filename.png". Hence, you will save resources and access the file easily.